# Unable to build Artifactory OSS 7.15 from source

Tags: maven, artifactory, building

I was trying to compile JFrog Artifactory from source code, but I ran into a maven issue.

Here are my steps:

- Download the latest source from https://releases.jfrog.io/artifactory/bintray-artifactory/org/artifactory/oss/jfrog-artifactory-oss/7.17.5/jfrog-artifactory-oss-7.17.5-sources.tar.gz
- Unzip it and run `mvn clean install` in the root directory
- Get an error

This is the error I got:

```
PS C:\Users\mTrachoz\Desktop\jfrog-artifactory-7.17.5> mvn clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for org.artifactory:artifactory-parent:7.17.5: Failure to find org.jfrog.common:jfrog-parent-pom:pom:7.17.2 in http://jcenter.bintray.com was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 22, column 13
 @
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project org.artifactory:artifactory-parent:7.17.5 (C:\Users\mTrachoz\Desktop\jfrog-artifactory-7.17.5\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for org.artifactory:artifactory-parent:7.17.5: Failure to find org.jfrog.common:jfrog-parent-pom:pom:7.17.2 in http://jcenter.bintray.com was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 22, column 13 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```